# angular *ngIf not working when ngstyle works

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

This is my angular code when bottom element load working
ngif is not working, why could be so?
Below there is component code and html , which are using in my snippet.
Problem is really strange, because code should work. But !loading expression works well for ngif.

Before loading;

[image]

After loading;

[image]

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Anular Application';
  //products: Iproduct[] = data;
  products: Iproduct[] = [];
  parentData: string = "This is parent data";
  details: boolean = false;
  loading: boolean = false;
  variable: boolean = true;
  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService,   ) {
  }

  //service proving us the data
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
      setTimeout(() => {}, 2000);
      this.products = products;
      this.loading = false;
      this.variable = false;
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center" [ngStyle]="{'visibility': loading ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }">Loading ngstyle 23..</h1>
<h1  *ngIf="loading" class="text-center">Loading if ..</h1>
<h1  *ngIf="!loading" class="text-center">not Loading if ..</h1>
<app-product-component [stringHardCode]="'string hardcoded'" [childData]="parentData" 
    *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" [product]="product">
```

Comment: It works just fine. You just claim it does not work.

Comment: Code looks fine. Could you provide more context?

Comment: @Antoniossss unfortunately no ,

Comment: @MrCodingB i am ataching  screenshots

Comment: We will need to see some code in addition to screenshots @Eugene

Comment: @Chris Gilardi  for sure, i was little bit updating, I didn't attach product service code, because problem not inside it, i think so cause one of headers working.

Comment: @MrCodingB I provided all content that might be.

Comment: @Antoniossss if it works just fine, can u explain why it doesn't in?

Comment: <h2>
    {{products[0].title}}
</h2>
tthis line leads to error somebody know why it could be and why ngstyle worked?

Comment: products[0]==null? ???

Comment: @Eugene I don't understand why you think your code is rock solid and one of most used (ergo tested) feature in one of most popular frameworks IN THE WORLD *does not work*. Its not like there some other issues with your code like eg what you have mentioned undefined products[0] or other stuff that you think are NOT relevant. After all you know what is relevant and not, but yet you seek help. How come?

Comment: @Eugene this is not a riddle solving site. I have feeling that you are like "ok I have a riddle for you, having a limited amount of information instead not what you would actually need, you have to magically solve the problem without even knowing what the problem is"

Comment: @antoniossss u dont understand? all users did it, ngIf not displaying value when nsgStyle displaying, on same condition, i provided component code and html, what do u need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1 class="text-center" [ngStyle]="{'visibility': loading ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }">Loading using ngStyle..</h1>
<h1 *ngIf="loading" class="text-center">Loading using *ngIf..</h1>
<h1 *ngIf="!loading" class="text-center">Not Loading using *ngIf..</h1>
<app-product-component
  [stringHardCode]="'string hardcoded'"
  [childData]="parentData"
  *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index"
  [product]="product">
</app-product-component>

 **.ts file**
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Angular Application';
  products: IProduct[] = [];
  parentData: string = "This is parent data";
  loading: boolean = true;
  variable: boolean = true;

  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.products = products;
        this.loading = false; 
        this.variable = false;
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
}
```

With these changes, the loading and conditional rendering should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Pratik was faster than me :) (You have a "type error", see where should be the `{` `}` in the setTimeout function), so only an advice:

If you want to simulate a "delay", you can also use the rxjs operator [delay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delay)

```
this.productsService.getProducts().pipe(
 delay(2000)
 ).subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products;
      this.loading = false;
      this.variable = false;
})
```

Comment: Where should there be a "type error" in OP's or Pratik's code?...an empty callback as a parameter to `setTimeout` - though useless - is valid code.

Comment: @MrCodingB, the error is in the code of Eugene, He wrote `setTimeout(() => {},2000);`. This code "makes nothing" (I imagine he want to make a delay). Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Yes I know, but as I explained, that's not an error, it's just useless code

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't seem to be with the `*ngIf` directive, but rather with your understanding and usage of the `setTimeout` function. The `setTimeout` function works by calling the provided callback function after a specified time has passed. It doesn't stop your code or introduce a delay in your code (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)). Therefore the issue is most likely that `productsService.getProducts` doesn't take a lot of time to complete and so the amount of time the loading text is displayed is too short for you to notice or even be rendered.

To make the loading text visible you'd have to actually introduce a delay that would allow the text to be displayed for long enough. This could be done in many ways, but mainly there are two options:

The first option would be using `setTimeout`, but fixing the empty callback:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loading = true;

  this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.products = products;
      this.loading = false;
      this.variable = false;
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

The second option would be to use the rxjs `delay` operator:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loading = true;

  this.productsService.getProducts()
    .pipe(delay(2000))
    .subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products;
      this.loading = false;
      this.variable = false;
    });
}
```